# UsageAggregates API of azure is giving a blank response with continuation token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I called below **AZURE API** from postman.

> https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{SubscriptionID}/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/UsageAggregates?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&reportedstartTime=2019-12-29T00%3a00%3a00%2b00%3a00&reportedEndTime=2019-12-30T00%3a00%3a00%2b00%3a00&$top=1

I got a response with empty value field along with some nextlink. when I again called the API with `Nextlink` URL response was having blank value field.

```
{
    "value": [],
    "nextLink": somelink
}
```

I am able to get proper response using same API for some different subscription.

Comment: Can you make sure that the subscription has a usage of resources?

Answer (score 0):

Empty Array shows that it doesn;t have any usage details available for requested time frame.

Firstly as suggested by Tony, check if you have the usage resource for the requested date.

```
 **Important**

Please note that the dateTime value format must be URL encoded as ISO 8601 format, and non-numeric characters must use escape codes (i.e. colon is escaped to %3a, plus sign is escaped to %2b) so that it is URI friendly. These refer to the start and end time ranges of your query. This dateTime parameter must also be specified in Universal Time Coordinated (UTC).
```

Secondly , Set {**`aggregationGranularity`**} to ‘Hourly’. This is an optional parameter with two discrete potential values: Daily and Hourly. As the values suggest, the former one returns the data in daily granularity whereas the latter one is hourly resolution. **`Daily`** is the default.

Sample URI:

```
**https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-Id}/providers/Microsoft.Commerce/UsageAggregates?api-version=2015-06-01-preview\&reportedStartTime=2014-05-01T00%3a00%3a00%2b00%3a00\&reportedEndTime=2015-06-01T00%3a00%3a00%2b00%3a00\&aggregationGranularity=Hourly\&showDetails=f**
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have enough permissions for the subscription in question.

Empty result `[]` can be returned when the permissions are missing. There is no error shown in such case.

The easiest way to ensure the permissions are available is to use Contributor or Owner role.

Additionally, `Get-UsageAggregates -Debug` (from Az PowerShell module) can be used to check how the request URL should look like.

```
 Get-UsageAggregates -ReportedStartTime "2022-05-24 10:00" -ReportedEndTime "2022-05-24 15:00" -Debug -AggregationGranularity Hourly
```